# WARN [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I have following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring3 mvc maven</name>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>






</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Alpha5</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version> <configuration> <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds> 
            <webApp> <contextPath>/spring3</contextPath> </webApp> </configuration> </plugin> -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>spring3</wtpContextName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<artifactId>kuppiWar</artifactId>
```

after successfull build when I try to deploy on wildfly 10.0 I get following warning error for each dependency jar

```
22:57:12,211 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/LocalJaxWsServiceFactoryBean.class at /C:/Users/admin/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/kuppiWar.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.verifyMagic(Indexer.java:1146)
at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1433)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

At end I get following error msg

```
22:57:12,315 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kuppiWar.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"kuppiWar.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"kuppiWar.war\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0161: Failed to get manifest for deployment \"/C:/Users/admin/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/kuppiWar.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar\"
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)"}}
```

22:57:12,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "kuppiWar.war" with deployment "kuppiWar.war"
22:57:12,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."kuppiWar.war".STRUCTURE
      service jboss.deployment.unit."kuppiWar.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kuppiWar.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "kuppiWar.war"

Answer (score 0):

- Check the deployment archive for corruption, and repackage it if necessary.
- If using "domain mode" and there is a firewall or other security policy between Domain Controller and Host Controller, or between 2 Host Controllers, file transferring might be blocked by firewall.In this case following error message would be thrown out.